# NGINX dynamic URL

Tags: linux, nginx

I am new to nginx. Please help in resolving an issue. We have multiple dynamics URL that will access the same resource.
URLs may be 
`http://5.3.5.11/t/1/ui3` where (/t/* can change to any random no)

```
listen 80;
server_name 5.3.5.11;
root /opt/retail/;
location ~*/ui3 {       
        try_files $uri $uri/ /ui3;      
    }
```

1. When I hit the URL `http://5.3.5.11/t/1/ui3` it get redirected to `http://5.3.5.11/ui3` but I want to remain the same (`http://5.3.5.11/t/1/ui3`). I the location block it should accessing the resource i.ei /ui3. How I can avoid changing of browser URL `http://5.3.5.11/t/1/ui3`
2. Can I set the pattern in location some thing like `location ~ */t/[0-9]+/ui3`.

Comment: How does your complete configuration look like?

Answer (score 1):

1. `try_files` merely does an *internal* redirect to the last parameter if no file specified before is found.
   Therefore, you should not notice any change to the URI. [TeroKilkanen](https://serverfault.com/users/210570/tero-kilkanen) asked for a complete configuration. You should provide a minimal working configuration reproducing the alleged behavior.
2. Regex `location`s support PCRE, thus why not? If you encounter trouble with PCRE, you should specify your question.